# StringConverter in a plugin

Tags: c#, plugins, properties, cad

I am developing a software which uses plug-ins. This is the [Building Patterns](http://buildingpatterns.com) . The foundation's possible solutions in dlls one by one. In the property handling of the building's foundation it's possible to choose from the list of foundation's types. 
The making of string list looks like the following:

```
    private string kindOf;                                          
    [TypeConverter(typeof(FileNames4Foundation)), CategoryAttribute("Foundation"), Description("Foundation pattern")]
    public string KindOf
    {
        get { return kindOf; }
        set
        {
            kindOf = value;
            Update();                       //update foundation
            RegistryWorks.WriteString("Foundation.KindOf", kindOf); //store setting up to the registry
        }
    }
```

The TypeConverter looks like this:

```
    public class FileNames4Foundation : StringConverter
{
    public string[] GetNames()
    {
        List<string> names = Utils.GetNames("\\RibbonPages\\Polygon\\Pattern\\Foundation\\", "dll");
        return names.ToArray();
    }
    public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        List<string> names = Utils.GetNames("\\RibbonPages\\Polygon\\Pattern\\Foundation\\", "dll");
        return new StandardValuesCollection(GetNames());
    }
}
```

This solution works absolutely right.

Now I had to change the program system like below. Until now the different building types was fixed in the program code. In the new system the building types will be loaded into the main program from plug-ins. The schema is the following:

```
Main program
- Mobil type facility plugin
    - 
    - 
- Polygon type facility plugin
    - Foundation
        - Bar plugin
        - Foot plugin
        - Slant plugin
    - Slab
        - Cantilever plugin
        - Normal plugin
    - Roof
        - Mansard plugin
        - Pitched plugin
- Tower type facility plugin
    -
    -
```

The change lead to plug-in handled listing of the plug-ins at the properties doesn't work. At debug we can see the program wasn't run till the "StringConverter" part.
I would like if the reading up the properties of the plug-ins would works in the new system as well.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I was able to solve the problem with I put the "StringConverter" classes to the lowest level.